# How to get the list of the Entitlement_Name__c from the Query?

Tags: apex

I am very new to the Apex Programming and just wanted to confirm below if possible

```
List<Entitlement_Setting__mdt> entitlementList = [Select Entitlement_Name__c
                                               From Entitlement_Setting__mdt
                                               WHERE Category__c='Auth.Net'
                                               AND Sub_Category__c='Basic Auth'
                                               AND Record_Type__c ='XXXXXXX'];
```

I know this query expects the list of `Entitlement_Setting__mdt`. But I only need to get the list of the `List<String> Entitlement_Name__c =` using this query can we do that ?

Please guide.

Comment: did you try it? Usually, the forum is here to help you if you are stuck with something that you tried, rather than how to and does this work questions. Feel free to visit [ask] and take the [tour]. =) The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/home)  and [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules) are a good place to start usually.

Comment: Yes I followed the SOQL Trailhead, but I dont find what I want. Its very different than SQL.

Comment: I think my point is, did you try? and if yes, what error message or setback are you encountering. there is plenty of documentation on SOQL

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight forward..
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/22/soql-how-i-query-with-thee-let-me-count-the-ways/

```
List<String> yourStrings = new List<String>();

for(Entitlement_Setting__mdt etl : [Select Entitlement_Name__c From Entitlement_Setting__mdt WHERE Category__c='Auth.Net' AND Sub_Category__c='Basic Auth' AND Record_Type__c ='XXXXXXX']])
{
   yourStrings.add(etl.Entitlement_Name__c );
}
```

Comment: In short, what I was expecting is not possible. Not sure why people downvote the questions.